# Undefined Citation natbib / Failing to print References

Tags: citing, natbib, undefined

I am using the natbib package to manage my references for my thesis. Unfortunately the citations are undefined and it prints "?" in the pdf rather than the actual Citation from my bib file. Neither are my references printed. I am using texmaker.
Does anybody know how to solve my problem? Do i have to compile it in a specific order? I usually compile: PDFLatex - Bibtex - PDFlatex - show pdf latex.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

%% Font
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%% Mathematics
\usepackage{amsmath, latexsym}
%% Graphics
\usepackage{graphicx}
%% Line spacing
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
%% Bibliography
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}
%% Hyperlinks
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{lscape}

\newcommand{\eg}{{\it e.g.}}
\newcommand{\ie}{{\it i.e.}}
\begin{document}

\newpage
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
    \setcounter{page}{2}

\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\thepage}{\arabic{page}}
\section{Introduction}

\section{Literature Review}

\section{Identity Index }

The identity index developed by FehrAdvice \& Partners AG measures a person's feeling of belonging to a particular cooparation. 
An identity is defined as a person's sense of self \citep{akerlof2000economics} .

\bibliography{References}


\end{document}
```

Comment: On first glance the code shown so far looks OK and the compilation cycle (LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX) is also OK. Can you show us the `.bib` entry `akerlof2000economics`. Please also check the `.blg` and `.log` files for warning or error messages.

Comment: if i run the .bib file following error appears: 
ERROR - Cannot find control file 'References.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX? INFO - ERRORS: 1. My bib file looks like follow: @article{akerlof2000economics,
  title={Economics and identity},
  author={Akerlof, George A and Kranton, Rachel E},
  journal={The Quarterly Journal of Economics},
  volume={115},
  number={3},
  pages={715--753},
  year={2000},
  publisher={MIT Press}
}

Comment: You appear to be running Biber, when you should be running BibTeX. Follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 in reverse to make sure your editor is configured to run BibTeX and not Biber. Note that in any case you don't run BibTeX or Biber on the `.bib` file, you run it on the basename of your `.tex` file (or BibTeX on the `.aux` and Biber on the `.bcf`).